# Make vertically centered div tag stick to top on window resize?

Tags: html, overflow

I'm building this portfolio website, and it needs to be vertically centered. The only problem is, when the window is resized vertically down past a certain point, the menubar is cut off. How can I get the site to stick when it touches the ceiling of the viewing area?

http://home.comcast.net/~swiftmail/aspect/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "stick" class dynamically with JavaScript.

```
#vertical_center .stick {
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

You may look at JS workaround to do this:
[Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa)

Comment: I have to admit I'm not very good at Javascript. Do you have any resources where I could look up how to do this?